# Converting String to array of characters

Tags: arrays, string, c#-4.0

Suppose I have a string:

```
string  test = "hello world";
```

How can I convert this string to an array of characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> char[] temp = test.ToCharArray();